# code not working: python print errors

Tags: python

Question:
You have a record of N students. Each record contains the student's name, and their percent marks in Maths, Physics and Chemistry. The marks can be floating values. The user enters some integer N followed by the names and N marks for students. You are required to save the record in a dictionary data type. The user then enters a student's name. Output the average percentage marks obtained by that student, correct to two decimal places.

My code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(raw_input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    line = raw_input().split()
    name, scores = line[0], line[1:]
    scores = map(float, scores)
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = raw_input()
query_name= str(query_name)
query_scores = student_marks[query_name]
print ("(0%.2f)".format(len(query_scores)/len(query_name)))
```

the wrong output im getting:
(0%.2f)

Answer (score 1):

You're combining two different ways of formatting: % and `.format()`. Change the last line to

`print ("%.2f" % (len(query_scores)/len(query_name)))`

Alternatively:

`print ("{:.2f}".format(len(query_scores)/len(query_name)))`

See https://pyformat.info/ for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting method for Python changed (see [link](https://pyformat.info)). Try the new style:

`print ("({:0.2f})".format(len(query_scores)/len(query_name)))`

Answer (score -1):

let suppose we take

> 93/47
>
> outputs 1.9787234042553192

to get formatted output till two decimal you can use

```
eval('{:.2f}'.format(93/47))
```

> the output is 1.98